Calling a constructor class with a mixin doesn't recognize constructor Arguments in typescript
I am attempting to understand why the following code does not work.
I have a mixin that produces an anonymous class. The resulting class has a constructor function with a defined list of arguments. However, when I try to create an instance of that class, TypeScript returns an error: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
Of course, I can define a constructor in the TestCase class, which resolves the issue. However, I would like to know why this code does not work as expected and if there is a way to make it work without needing to add a constructor to every extended class.
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function mixin<T extends Constructor>(Base: T) {
  return class extends Base {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
    }
  };
}

@mixin
class TestCase {
}

new TestCase(1) // <- Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Playground

What is your mixin doing that motivates allowing adding constructor arguments that the parent constructor doesn't expect? Right now the error you're getting looks like a good one, of course new TestCase(1) should be a problem, since TestCase doesn't expect 1.  I'm not sure what the goal is... do you want @mixin to produce constructors that allow arbitrary constructor arguments and passes them to super() even if super doesn't expect them? Why?

My intention is to share logic between parent and child classes in Next.js. For some reason, when I use inheritance, TypeScript does not assign properties of the child class if they are not present in the parent class. As a workaround, I implemented a decorator to address this issue. While the decorator works as expected, TypeScript does not recognize the number of arguments (arity) unless I explicitly specify it. I am trying to understand how to leverage TypeScript effectively without having to duplicate logic throughout my codebase.

But the example you’re showing doesn’t even begin to do anything with constructor arguments, it just passes them. Maybe you could edit the code to be a [mre] that motivates what you’re asking for? Right now I agree fully with the compiler not letting you do that.  Decorators never mutate the type of the class so you can’t do it as a decorator but you might be able to do it with a function call… right now there’s still no obvious reason to support it.

(see prev comment), like this playground link shows a possible path, but I have no idea why I'd want to do this, unless you [edit] with a [mre] that motivates it.

@jcalz  thank you, your example shows me the way how I can resolve it, though it is not ideal, but I would not agree with you that decorator doesn't change the class, please see Working Example, and this is why I am confused, decorator works, but typing system without additional changes doesn't work

Decorators do not mutate the type of the class as seen by TypeScript. This is not my opinion, it's a fact about TypeScript; there's ms/TS#4881. Now that ES Decorators are part of TS and they are no longer experimental, maybe this will be implemented someday? But for now, @dec class Foo { ⋯ } does not and cannot mutate Foo as far as TS sees. I can write up an answer but I really really wish you had [edit]ed to show a [mre] that does something. I suppose it doesn't help if I ask a third time.

@jcalz Go ahead and add your answer as it actually solves the issue. I guess typescript will not make it easy, and I am not able to share types and logic with one decorator as I want to. I am trying to build records based API schema something like this API Records so I can share API across all models.

You can't use a decorator to change the apparent type of a class in TypeScript. This is currently true for both the new ECMAScript decorators released with TypeScript 5.0  and the older experimental TypeScript decorators.
That means if your decorator is a mixin and it adds a property or changes the constructor parameters, that change will not be visible to TypeScript (even though it will of course happen at runtime):
function mixin<C extends new (...args: any) => any>(Base: C) {
  return class extends Base {
    addedProp = "abc"; // adds a property
    constructor(...args: any) {
      super(...args);
    }
  };
}

@mixin class TestCase {
  constructor(public prop: number) { }
}
const testCase = new TestCase(1); // okay
console.log(testCase.prop.toFixed(2)); // "1.00"
console.log(testCase.addedProp.toString()); // "ABC" error!
//                   ~~~~~~~~~
// Property 'addedProp' does not exist on type 'TestCase'.

So you shouldn't use decorators as mixins, unless the mixin isn't supposed to change the type of the class constructor. This is a documented limitation of decorators as mixins.There is a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#4881 to support mutating the type of a class, but it has yet to be implemented as of TypeScript 5.6.
Instead of using a mixin as a decorator, you can still just use it as a regular function call:
const TestCase = mixin(
  class TestCase {
    constructor(public prop: number) { }
  }
);

const testCase = new TestCase(1); // okay
console.log(testCase.prop.toFixed(2)) // "1.00"
console.log(testCase.addedProp.toUpperCase()); // "ABC"


Unfortunately another issue with mixins is that you can't easily write them to change the constructor parameters. There is an open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#37143 to allow this sort of thing, but it's not implemented.
Presumably the only reason you'd want new TestCase(1) to succeed when class TestCase {} has a zero-arg constructor is because the mixin uses that 1 in an added property. (I've asked several times why one would want to pass 1 as an argument to the super constructor if it doesn't expect such an argument and I've yet to hear a cogent reply. So I will assume the mixin uses the first argument and passes the rest of them along).
But due to the lack of microsoft/TypeScript#37143, the obvious implementation gives an error:
function mixin<C extends new (...args: any) => any>(Base: C) {
  return class extends Base { // error!
    //   ~~~~~ error! A mixin class must have a constructor 
    //  with a single rest parameter of type 'any[]'.(2545)
    constructor(public addedProp: string, ...args: ConstructorParameters<C>) {
      super(...args);
    }
  }
}

So if you want this to happen, you'll need to take a lot more direct control over the types. You'll have to write out what you expect the mixin to do, explictly, and use lots of type assertions to quell compiler errors:
function mixin<A extends any[], T extends object>(Base: new (...args: A) => T) {
  return class extends (Base as any) {
    constructor(public addedProp: string, ...args: A) {
      super(...args);
    }
  } as new (addedProp: string, ...args: A) => (T & { addedProp: string })
}

Now when you call it, the returned constructor type prepends the new argument to the list the super constructor expected, and returns an instance type with the added property:
const TestCase = mixin(
  class TestCase {
    constructor(public prop: number) { }
  }
);
/* const TestCase: new (addedProp: string, prop: number) => TestCase & {
  addedProp: string;
} */

const testCase = new TestCase("abc", 1);
console.log(testCase.prop.toFixed(2)) // "1.00"
console.log(testCase.addedProp.toUpperCase()) // "ABC"


So right now that's how one might proceed until the above feature requests are implemented, if ever: use mixins as function calls and not as decorators, and be prepared to use a lot of type juggling in the mixin call signature to have it behave as desired.
Playground link to code

Thank you for such a comprehensive and detailed response!
